# customized elb security policy in aws possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Recently someone from us has made SecurityCheck against our domain. He has found that we still support insecure Ciphers. We should stop this asap. Since our domain points to an aws application elb, we have to change that there.

In aws application elb settings we could only select one of the predefined security policies. None of them fulfills anything we need. We have not found any way to define and use own customized policy. Maybe anyone has any tips for us?

Comment: Is it ELB or ALB 
?

Comment: it is ALB, Application Load Balancer

Answer (score 1):

Someone from aws support center has answered my question. It is unfortunately not possible to use any customized policy.

```
*I understand you would like to define and use your own customized policy, but unfortunately, Network Load Balancers do not support custom security policies.  For more information on on security policies, see [4].**
```